# How to get back to where i was after using auto complete in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I am using auto complete feature of Android Studio to add fields to my classes very often, first i write the name of the field i want to add and assign a value to it like :

[image]

then i press alt+enter to get suggetions and pick "create field ..", then it auto creates my field at the top of the class and takes the cursor there :

[image]

i press enter twice to confirm type and name of the field, and the cursor then stays at the end of the declaration rather than go back to where i was in the first place.

This is very annoying as i have to find where i was out of all those code lines, anyone knows how to avoid it and get back to where i was without navigating manually? maybe there is a way to make auto complete not to ask for validating the field and by doing so it would not have to take the cursor there?

I tried using alt+left arrow, but this takes me to weird places...

Comment: `Ctrl+click` on the variable to go back to a usage of it? If it's just been created, you'll jump to where it is.

Comment: @Harmelodic NICE! ill use that and see :) thanks!

Comment: I'll add it as the answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Click</kbd> on the variable you'll be able to jump to the next usage of that variable.

As you've just created the variable and this is your first time referring to it, this method should take you straight to where you were previously working.

This shortcut is also applicable to things other than variables (i.e. methods etc.)